# How to get the type of a cell in Libreoffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

I would like to know if a cell is a date, a number, a string or what. It would help a lot, exactly what/how should be done with it.

I think, librecalc knows it, because it affects the behavior of the cells on many ways (for example, date fields are converted by the actually used date format). But I did not find anything, how could I extract this important info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [TYPE](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Information_Functions#TYPE) function which:

> TYPE
> Returns the type of value, where 1 = number, 2 = text, 4 = Boolean value, 8 = formula, 16 = error value, 64 = array.
>
> If an error occurs, the function returns a logical or numerical value.

Dates are stored as numbers, so a date returns the value of 1.

Comment: Thanks, that is nice! However, there is still a difference between "24576" and a date "1994-03-05", even if its backend representation is the same. I think your answer could be made much more helpful if there would be some way to know even that.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to a bunch of other functions is available in `CELL(...)`

Now:
`=CELL("FORMAT",A1)` or even `=CELL("TYPE",A1)`
... seems as an alternative to `=TYPE(...)`
Still with some idiosyncrasy though.